# Beautifulsoup has confused with the element selected while scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** all the items in the table but, beautifulsoup return NONE to even when I selected the right element, any idea? Here's the [website link](https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=3171857)

```
url = 'https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=3171857'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'table':'InputTable2'})
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this `table = soup.find('table', attrs={'table':'InputTable2'})` the attrs should be `class` and not `table`.

You should also use `headers` in your request as this site is responding with a `503` without using headers.

Also, the URL that you have mentioned loads the content from another link.

> This: https://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/viewHtml?e=3171857

- Change your URL to the above one.
- Use `headers` in your request

  > headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'}
- You have to select the table that has the `class` = `InputTable2`. So use this

  > `table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'InputTable2'})`